# Date time error in production only

Tags: asp.net, production, datetime-format

I have two textbox on my asp.net page which are taking dates from calendar control:

On Calendar selection, I am assigning the value of selected have to hidden variable.
below is the code:

```
DateTime dtOne;
            dtOne = Convert.ToDateTime(hdnOne.Value.Trim().ToString());
            DateTime dtTwo = Convert.ToDateTime(hdnTwo.Value.Trim().ToString());
```

When keeping breakpoint I get this value for dtOne

> 9/2/2011 02:03...

It is working fine in pre prod deployed site, but when I copy paste the same deployed code to the production I am getting below error:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
```

Any suggestion why it happened and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Culture settings on your server are most likely different from the one your development machine. In this case I would think the DateSeperator is the culprit.

Have you compared the value of hdnOne.Value.Trim().ToString() on both enviromnents?

Comment: Replace "en-GB" with the culture of your choice: 
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");
Convert.ToDateTime(hdnOne.Value.Trim().ToString(), ci);

Answer (score 3):

Yep - this is a Regional Settings problem. Essentially, the format string you're using in Convert.ToDateTime isn't able to parse the datetime returned by the Production server. So either change your Production server Regional Settings, or if this is unpalatable (and it might be) use an appropriate IFormatProvider parameter in the method parameters to explain which datetime format the returned string is actually in so that it can parse it.

Info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.todatetime.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Is there any difference between your production and testing environments - especially with regards to Culture/Locale? - maybe try explicitly matching the Culture used by both your javascript calendar control and your code's Parse.

Is this exception being thrown with all content? Or just some user content? If you are using TextBox's then this could be just some users (or users in some locales) entering unexpected content.

Regardless of this current fix, you will need to expect this error at runtime once real users get their hands on your web pages - so either handle the FormatException or use TryParse

Comment: Text box is in read only mode. I have no idea how to find differnce between two server culture, is there any way I can do that ?

Comment: Check out this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx - it will let you set the Culture for the Parse operation

Answer (score 0):

if textbox is in readonly mode, then you will get blank when you will fetch the value from textbox. also use datetime.tryparse instead of convert